# Overriding hashCode when using isAssignableFrom on equals method

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I need to find a way to cache Methods(`java.lang.reflect.Method`) in such a way that whenever I call a function with the class (`Class`) methodName(`String`) and arguments(`T[]`) the function will return the cached method if exists or find the method, add it to the cache and return it.

I want to use HashMap for caching so I can find the method in O(1) but the problem is that I need to use`isAssignableFrom` when I override the equals method:

```
public class A1 extends AParent {}

public class A2 extends AParent {}

public class AParent {}

public class Temp{
    public void testFunc(AParent a){}
}
```

This is the class I use for the keys in the HashMap :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MethodAbs{
Class c;
String methodName;
Class<?>[] argsTypes;

public MethodAbs(Class c, String methodName, Class<?>[] argsTypes){
    this.c = c;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.argsTypes = argsTypes;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MethodAbs methodAbs = (MethodAbs) o;

    if (c != null ? !c.equals(methodAbs.c) : methodAbs.c != null) return false;
    if (methodName != null ? !methodName.equals(methodAbs.methodName) : methodAbs.methodName != null)
        return false;
    return isArgsTypesEq(argsTypes, methodAbs.argsTypes);

}

//a method is equals to the one cached if the arguments types
// can be cast to the ones that are saved on the map,
// i.e the ones on the method declaration 

private boolean isArgsTypesEq(Class<?>[] at1, Class<?>[] at2){
    boolean res = at1.length == at2.length;
    for(int i = 0; i<at1.length && res; i++){
        if(!at1[i].isAssignableFrom(at2[i])) res = false;
    }
    return res;
}


//default implementation (not working properly!)

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = c != null ? c.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (methodName != null ? methodName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(argsTypes);
    return result;
}


}
```

The class I use for caching

```
class Run{

public Map<MethodAbs, Method> map = new HashMap<>();

public<T> Method myFunc(Class c, String methodName, T[] args){
    MethodAbs ma = new MethodAbs(c, methodName, getTypes(args));
    if(map.containsKey(ma)){
        return map.get(ma);
    }
    else{
        for(Method method: c.getMethods()){
            MethodAbs currMethodAbs = new MethodAbs(c, method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            if(!map.containsKey(currMethodAbs))
                map.put(currMethodAbs, method);
            if(currMethodAbs.equals(ma)) break;
        }
    }
    return map.get(ma);
}

private<T> Class<?>[] getTypes(T[] args) {
    Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[args.length];
    for(int i = 0; i< args.length; i++){
        types[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
    return types;
}
}
```

And Main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Run r = new Run();
    Object [] arr = new Object[1];
    arr[0] = new A1();
    r.myFunc(Temp.class, "testFunc", arr);
    arr[0] = new A2();
    r.myFunc(Temp.class, "testFunc", arr);

}
```

In the scenario above after calling r.myFunc for the first time, the map looks like this:

```
MethodAbs(Temp.class, "testFunc", [AParent.class])
```

on the second time map.containsKey will return false(because AParent.hashCode != A2.hashCode) but they are `equals`.

- The hierarchy shown in the example will not necessarily look like that(for example A2 can be a grandchild of AParent)

I know I can use the Class and method name as keys and the value will be a list of methods which I'll need to iterate and compare with equals but I'm trying to find a better way...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're `equals` method is fundamentally broken, for at least two reasons.

1. It is not symmetric, see the following code snippet:

   ```
   public static void main(String... args) {
       MethodAbs methodValueOfObject = new MethodAbs(String.class, "valueOf", new Class<?>[] { Object.class });
       MethodAbs methodValueOfCharArrays = new MethodAbs(String.class, "valueOf", new Class<?>[] { char[].class });
       System.out.println(methodValueOfObject.equals(methodValueOfCharArrays)); // prints "true"
       System.out.println(methodValueOfCharArrays.equals(methodValueOfObject)); // prints "false"
   }
   ```
2. It equates methods which you probably don't mean to be considered equal. To see that imagine that your `Temp` class has two `testFunc` methods, `public void testFunc(A1 a)` and `public void testFunc(A2 a)`. The corresponding `MethodAbs` objects shouldn't be equal, but according to your implementation, they indeed are.

I think that the best solution for you is to just get rid of the cache altogether. Just use

```
public Method getMethod(Class<?> c, String methodName, Class<?>... paramClasses) {
    try {
        return c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramClasses);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // Your exception handling goes here
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Class` objects are already cached by the classloader, so the performance loss is negligible.

Comment: I agree with the broken symmetry issue, however I can not use getDecleredMethod because it is expecting to receive the exact object type of the method. in the example above calling it with Class A1 will throw an exception because it is looking for Class AParent. Any ideas on how to fix that?